# How do i have have a related list for quote in Opportunity in Lightning UI?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have Quotes related list on the opportunity layout and i can see the related list on the aloha layout. But when i switch to the Lightning layout i cant see quotes there, but i can see the options to add contact roles, opportunity product, Files and Notes.

Is there a different layout for the lightning? Where can i find that?

Answer (score 3):

You cant find Quotes on Lightning UI because its still not supported .

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_rightforme

> Salesforce Classic might be right for you if:
>
> - Your sales team makes regular use of features that aren’t yet    available in Lightning Experience, such as quotes, forecasting, or
>     territory management.
> - You primarily use customer service tools or other non-sales features.
> - You want a single experience for your sales and service teams.

Comment: standard object `Order` is supported as a related list in `Opportunity` using lightning UI ?